# Why do we need Redis for running CKAN?

Tags: redis, ckan, rhel7

I was wondering why do we need Redis server for running CKAN.

If needed, why? And How do I configure it with CKAN?

p.s
I am running my ckan instance in RHEL7.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Redis has been a requirement [since CKAN 2.7](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/changelog.html#v2-7-0-2017-08-02), when a new system for asynchronous background jobs was introduced which relies on Redis. You can configure the Redis connection using the [`ckan.redis.url`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-redis-url) option.

<s>Redis is not required for the current version of CKAN (2.6.2 at the time of this writing), it's [not even mentioned](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.6.2/search.html?q=redis&check_keywords=yes&area=default) in the CKAN 2.6.2 documentation.</s>

<s>However, the upcoming 2.7 release [will require Redis](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/73381ea2338ef1d04b37c907721c0076a2a86462/doc/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.rst) for its [new system of asynchronous background jobs](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3165). Redis will be configured using the new [`ckan.redis.url` option](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/73381ea2338ef1d04b37c907721c0076a2a86462/doc/maintaining/configuration.rst#redis-settings).</s>

Comment: where can I find the docs explaining what exact background jobs in CKAN Redis support? More explicitly, what processes would fail if Redis was not configured correctly?

Comment: @KasiaKulma: It has been some time since I've worked with CKAN, but i I remember correctly then by default the background jobs (and hence Redis) are not required. If an extension requires background jobs that is usually listed in the documentation (see, for example, the docs for [ckanext-extractor](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-extractor)).

Comment: Thanks, @FlorianBruckner, makes sense. Also, it looks like this link answers my question https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/background-tasks.html