# What can be done using CKAN's asynchronous background jobs?

Tags: redis, ckan

I have just started installing CKAN.

I was looking in the initial documentation to install CKAN and on the principal website of ckan.org, its impossible for me to find and know why Redis is necessary to run a version 2.7 or higher of CKAN.

For example: 
[Why do we need Redis for running CKAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110019/why-do-we-need-redis-for-running-ckan)

In this question, it says that its necessary for the new system of asynchronous background jobs that is it used on CKAN. So what type of asynchronous job can do CKAN? and when CKAN can use this type of asynchronous background jobs?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question: redis is used as storage backend for the background worker.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, CKAN core only provides [the infrastructure for asynchronous background jobs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/background-tasks.html) but doesn't actually create such jobs on its own (this might change in future releases).

There are, however, CKAN extensions that use the system, for example [ckanext-extractor](https://github.com/stadt-karlsruhe/ckanext-extractor).

*Disclosure: I'm the author of ckanext-extractor.*